# Filter DNS Forwarded responses with Bind

Tags: dns, bind

What options do I have for blocking DNS query responses containing a specific IP address or range?

I'm reading up on [DNS Rebinding attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding), and wondering how I might block them.

When an attacker attempts a rebinding attack, they will attempt to trick the browser into believing that the malicious content was served from `127.0.0.1` or an address within my LAN. They do so by configuring their DNS server to serve the fraudulent address (when queried from within the malicious script).  I would like to prevent this by blocking all responses to forwarded DNS queries that result in a local or LAN address.

I use a Bind9 zone for my local network and use forwarders to resolve external addresses.

The Bind box is a Debian server behind my NAT router. It runs UFW for firewall, and allows TCP/UDP over port 53.

Comment: Have you read up on Response Policy Zones (RPZ), they can do what you want and is included in BIND9.  https://dnsrpz.info/

Comment: I don't think that RPZ can be used for this. I believe that RPZ is only capable of filtering requests. The question refers to responses from unknown request domains but with local addresses in the response. Bind does have a feature to do this as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get Bind to filter the addresses returned using the `deny-answer-addresses` feature. To use this add the following to the `options` section of your `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` configuration file:

```
deny-answer-addresses { 192.0.2.0/24; } except-from { "example.net"; };
```

This will prevent any 192.0.2.x address from being returned in response to any DNS query except from the locally hosted `example.net` domain.

The Bind manual also recommends filtering aliases with:

```
deny-answer-aliases { "example.net"; };
```

A suggested set of filters I found at http://www.sput.nl/internet/dns-morons.html seems to cover the most common DNS rebinding attacks based on my own testing:

```
deny-answer-addresses {
    // Unconfigured
    0.0.0.0;
    // RFC 1918
    10.0.0.0/8;
    172.16.0.0/12;
    192.168.0.0/16;
    // RFC 3927
    169.254.0.0/16;
    // IPv6
    // :: to ::ffff:ffff:ffff.
    // Includes ::, ::1, IPv4-Compatible IPv6 Addresses ::/96,
    // and IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses ::ffff:0:0/96
    ::/80;
    // IPv6 Link local
    fe80::/10;
    // RFC 6052
    64:ff9b::/96;
} except-from { "Your.Domain"; };
deny-answer-aliases { "Your.Domain"; };
```

It's probably not a good idea to exclude `127.0.0.0/8` as it is often used by services like spam block lists.

Comment: Thank you! I'll evaluate your response over the coming weekend, when I have a little time to fiddle with it. looks promising.

Comment: Sorry for the significant delay in acceptance. I've looked into this config, and it looks like what I was looking for. I do wish I was finding a good way to test it though. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I used Brannon Dorsey's http://rebind.network test site (code https://github.com/brannondorsey/dns-rebind-toolkit) and wireshark to test. Not comprehensive but easy enough to test before and after enabling the change.